# display inline-block doesn't work in my code?

Tags: html, css

I am doing a basic html course on freecodecamp and I made this work properly. When i tried doing some changes on my own and adding different stuff to it it acted weird. I then decided to delete all my changes and re-launch but then it just didn't look the same as before. I have tried messing with different setups for my articles, tried adding new sections, articles and paragraphs but to me, it seems as if the code doesn't act like it did before. I have not just double og triple but quintuple checked my code to make sure it's identical to the one on freecodecamp and it IS, but it doesn't look the same at all. I don't know if I'm missing something, but if someone could figure out where the problem occurs, maybe i could stop banging my head against my table.
I want the paragraphs to be on the same line and I want my articles to be separated on each line.

Result:

[image: Result]

```css
h1,
p,
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.menu {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

body {
  background-image: url("Baggrund_2.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.på_linje {
  display: inline-block;
}

.smag,
.sandwich {
  text-align: left;
  width: 75%;
}

.pris {
  text-align: right;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>ProteinRiget</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="menu">
    <header>
    <h1>ProteinRiget</h1>
    <p>Est. 2027</p>
    </header>
  </body>
  <main>
    <section>
      <h2>Shakes & Smoothies</h2>
      <article class="på_linje">
        <p class="smag">John F. Kennedy shake</p>
        <p class="pris">50,-</p>
      </article>
      <article class="på_linje">
        <p class="smag">John snow shake</p>
        <p class="pris">50,-</p>
      </article>
      <article class="på_linje">
        <p class="smag">John Wayne shake</p>
        <p class="pris">50,-</p> 
      </article>
      <article class="på_linje">
        <p class="smag">John Cena shake</p>
        <p class="pris">50,-</p>
      </article>
      <article class="på_linje">
        <p class="smag">John Mayer shake</p>
        <p class="pris">50,-</p>
      </article>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>Sandwiches</h2>
      <article class="på_linje">
        <p class="sandwich">John(ny) Depperoni</p>
        <p class="pris">60,-</p>
      </article>
      <article class="på_linje">
        <p class="sandwich">John(ny) Bravoioli</p>
        <p class="pris">65,-</p>
      </article>
      <article class="på_linje">
        <p class="sandwich">John(ny) Knoxckle</p>
        <p class="pris">50,-</p>
      </article>
      <article class="på_linje">
        <p class="sandwich">John(ny) Deluxe</p>
        <p class="pris">70,-</p>
      </article>
    </section>
    </div>
  </main>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please add your code as text, not as image

Comment: What's the tutorial you are following?

Comment: The tutorial is https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/2022/responsive-web-design/learn-basic-css-by-building-a-cafe-menu/

Comment: It's almost like there is some "pre" setting that has been changed and now any code won't behave as it used to. I tried writing the start just like in the beginning of the course again and the results are just different from when i did this yesterday.

Comment: Just to make sure, change class name from `på_linje` to proper naming like `pa_linje` or something, check just incase

Comment: Okay. Did that, still no change.

Comment: Okay i figured out the problem. I needed to add a "p" after the class definition on "pa_linje", so it says: .pa_linje p { display: inline block; } instead of: .pa_linje {display: inline block; }

Answer (score 0):

> I want the paragraphs to be on the same line and I want my articles to be separated on each line.

For this, your paragraph needs to be inline-block and the article should be block.